# Spring boot clouyd stream with different input and output type

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

IN Spring boot Kafka STream I have following KStream:

```
Function<KStream<String,InputType>, KStream<String, OutputType>> process() {
}
```

So here input is of `InputType` object and output content is `OutputType` object. For this I want to write a custom serde. What my understanding is that in Serde ser/der should be of same data type. SO how can I write a serde that accept one object and send other object. OR SHoul I consider custom ser/deser in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two custom `Serde` implementations - something like
`InputTypeSerde implements Serde<InputType>` and `OutputTypeSerde implements Serde<OutputType>`. Then you can create two separate beans for them in your application. Binder should pick them up and assign them to the proper input and output bindings.